# Image Upload in Admin Panel

Tags: image, admin-panel, varien-file-uploader

I am developing a custom module. In this regard I have to upload image in admin panel. I found below codes in some tutorial.

```
$uploader->setAllowRenameFiles(true);
$uploader->setFilesDispersion(false);
$uploader->setAllowCreateFolders(true);
```

I would like to know more about these lines. What do they mean ??

Answer (score 1):

- $uploader->setAllowRenameFiles(true);   //if true, uploaded file's name will be changed, if file with the same name already exists directory. Necessary to avoid conflicts
- $uploader->setFilesDispersion(false); //To have a dispersion based on the original file name (as the file option does), we will have to do it manually
- $uploader->setAllowCreateFolders(true); //for creating the directory if not exists